# How to make sure the stride for discontiguous numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

Here is an example when I use numpy and try to understand the strides of an array

```py
import numpy as np
m = np.arange(6, dtype=np.uint8).reshape(2, 3)
print(m.shape, m.strides)
# m.shape: (2, 3)  m.strides:(3, 1)
m = m.transpose(1, 0)
print(m.shape, m.strides)
# m.shape:(3, 2) m.strides:(1, 3)
```

Till now, it's all fine...the shape and the strides are all easily to understand.
And array `m` now is discontiguous. But when I try to `expand_dims` for `m` :

```py
x = np.expand_dims(m, 0)
print(x.shape, x.strides)
# x.shape: (1, 3, 2)  x.strides:(3, 1, 3)
y = np.expand_dims(m, 1)
print(y.shape, y.strides)
# y.shape: (3, 1, 2)  y.strides:(1, 6, 3)
z = np.expand_dims(m, 2)
print(z.shape, z.strides)
# z.shape:(3, 2, 1) z.strides:(1, 3, 3)
```

I just can't understand the why the expanded dims' strides of `x, y, z` are `3, 6, 3`?

Is there a formula or document that can help me to understand the strides for discontiguous array?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to understand numpy strides for layman?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53097952/how-to-understand-numpy-strides-for-layman)

Comment: Thanks a lot, but my question is about the expanded dim's stride when the array is non-contiguous, rather than the strides of contiguous array.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [25]: m = np.arange(6, dtype=np.uint8).reshape(2, 3)
```

As you note the strides get reversed in the transpose:

```
In [26]: m.strides, m.T.strides
Out[26]: ((3, 1), (1, 3))

In [27]: m
Out[27]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]], dtype=uint8)

In [28]: m.T
Out[28]: 
array([[0, 3],
       [1, 4],
       [2, 5]], dtype=uint8)
```

We can picture that from the display.  For `m`, to go down rows we step by 3.  For `m.T` to go across columns we step by 3.

`expand_dims` uses `reshape`:

```
In [31]: m1=m.reshape(1,2,3);m1.strides,m1
Out[31]: 
((6, 3, 1),
 array([[[0, 1, 2],
         [3, 4, 5]]], dtype=uint8))
```

The meaning of the `6` becomes more obvious when we do a repeat:

```
In [32]: m1.repeat(2,0)      # (6,3,1) strides
Out[32]: 
array([[[0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5]],

       [[0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5]]], dtype=uint8)
```

To go down one plane or block, we step by 6.  (`m1` is a `view`, but the repeat is a copy, with its own data.)

Adding a dimension in the middle, we just have to "repeat" the `3`:

```
In [36]: m2=m.reshape(2,1,3).repeat(2,axis=1);m2.strides, m2
Out[36]: 
((6, 3, 1),
 array([[[0, 1, 2],
         [0, 1, 2]],
 
        [[3, 4, 5],
         [3, 4, 5]]], dtype=uint8))
```

Doing the same to the transpose doesn't add any complications.

Your `x` case, adding a leading dimension to the transpose (with repeat for clarity):

```
In [38]: m.T.reshape(1,3,2).repeat(2,axis=0)
Out[38]: 
array([[[0, 3],
        [1, 4],
        [2, 5]],

       [[0, 3],
        [1, 4],
        [2, 5]]], dtype=uint8)
```

The new first dimension steps by a block of 6.

While the contiguity flags make some sense when dealing with 2d array, and sometimes are relevant when passing arrays to specialized compiled code, they aren't as meaningful when looking a 3d+ arrays.  It's easy to make arrays, especially views, that aren't contiguous in either sense.

In recent [Indexing on ndarrays result in wrong shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75689070/indexing-on-ndarrays-result-in-wrong-shape/75690136#75690136), I explore what happens to strides when we apply advanced indexing to columns.

### edit

Your case where you get a 6:

```
In [61]: np.expand_dims(m.T,1)
Out[61]: 
array([[[0, 3]],

       [[1, 4]],

       [[2, 5]]], dtype=uint8)

In [62]: _.strides    # 1st dim steps by 1, last by 3
Out[62]: (1, 6, 3)
```

It's harder to visualize the blocks of 6 for the middle dimension, but it's doing the same thing as with the non-transpose.  The strides of the repeat don't help, because it's a copy:

```
In [63]: np.expand_dims(m.T,1).repeat(2,1)
Out[63]: 
array([[[0, 3],
        [0, 3]],

       [[1, 4],
        [1, 4]],

       [[2, 5],
        [2, 5]]], dtype=uint8)
In [64]: _.strides
Out[64]: (4, 2, 1)
```

We could get the same [61] by first expanding, and then transposing:

```
In [66]: np.expand_dims(m,0).transpose(2,0,1)
Out[66]: 
array([[[0, 3]],

       [[1, 4]],

       [[2, 5]]], dtype=uint8)   
In [67]: _.shape,_.strides
Out[67]: ((3, 1, 2), (1, 6, 3))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you do the transpose for `m`, the array changes from a `C_CONTIGUOUS` to `F_CONTIGUOUS`:

```
m = np.arange(6, dtype=np.uint8).reshape(2, 3)
print(m.flags)
```

flags of m

```
C_CONTIGUOUS : True
F_CONTIGUOUS : False
OWNDATA : False
...
```

For n

```
n = m.transpose(1, 0)
print(n.flags)
```

flags of n

```
C_CONTIGUOUS : False
F_CONTIGUOUS : True
OWNDATA : False
...
```

Then we look into the `array_interface` :

```
m.__array_interface__

{'data': (1840062163472, False),
 'strides': None,
 'descr': [('', '|u1')],
 'typestr': '|u1',
 'shape': (2, 3),
  'version': 3}
```

and for n :

```
n.__array_interface__

{'data': (1840062163472, False),
 'strides': (1, 3),
 'descr': [('', '|u1')],
 'typestr': '|u1',
 'shape': (3, 2),
 'version': 3}
```

We find that after the transpose, the key `strides` is assigned by a value `(1, 3)`.
Refer to this answer : [How does NumPy's transpose() method permute the axes of an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32034565/17457846). We know the transpose swaps the shape and stride information for each axis. In this process, the key `strides` is assigned.

And when you use `expand_dims` then calculate the `strides`. **Here I'm not sure**, I think  it takes the `strides` in the `__array_interface__`, then insert a stride based on the axis you called in the `expand_dims`. For example :

```
m = np.arange(6, dtype=np.uint8).reshape(2, 3)
n = m.transpose(1, 0)
y = np.expand_dims(n, 1)
y.strides
# (1, 6, 3)
```

So if you don't want to change the array to `F_CONTIGUOUS`, need to use `np.ascontiguousarray` after the transpose, which gives you a good result.

```
m = np.arange(6, dtype=np.uint8).reshape(2, 3)
a = np.ascontiguousarray(m.transpose(1, 0))
x = np.expand_dims(a, 0)
print(x.shape, x.strides)
# (1, 3, 2) (6, 2, 1)
y = np.expand_dims(a, 1)
print(y.shape, y.strides)
# (3, 1, 2) (2, 2, 1)
z = np.expand_dims(a, 2)
print(z.shape, z.strides)
# (3, 2, 1) (2, 1, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I am just curious about why `expand_dims(n, 1).strides[1]` is 6? How is this calculated？

Comment: That's the part I'm confused, as I wrote I'm not sure if it's a bug after transposing an array, `numpy` will fill the `strides`.  The `expand_dims(n, 1)[:, 0, :]` have 6 elements, I guess the 6 is from this axis.